# What is the best way to achieve a gradually changing color area chart with JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

I want to use JFreeChart to achieve a smooth area chart. I try to use `XYAreaRenderer2` to achieve it, but the drawn lines are not smooth:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To5Wu.png).
I want to achieve a smooth area chart, and gradient paint. How should I achieve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 创建数据集
    TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("");
    List<Double> values = Lists.newArrayList(
     26900.620000,26898.430000, 26903.000000, 26895.530000, 26882.520000, 26898.770000, 26891.690000, 26899.680000,
     26908.200000,26902.770000,26902.77,26902.77,26912.630000,26908.410000
    );
    Date start = null, end = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        Date time = new Date();
        if (i == 0) {
            start = time;
        }
        end = time;
        series.add(new Second(time), values.get(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    dataset.addSeries(series);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "", 
            "", 
            "", 
            dataset, 
            false, 
            false, 
            false
    );
    
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
   
    XYAreaRenderer2 renderer = new XYAreaRenderer2();
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0, new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(-5.0,-5.0,10.0,10.0));
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setOutline(true);
    renderer.setSeriesFillPaint(0, new Color(0, 0, 255, 63));
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2f));
    renderer.setSeriesShape(1, new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(-5.0,-5.0,10.0,10.0));
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.ORANGE);
    renderer.setOutline(true);
    renderer.setSeriesFillPaint(1, new Color(255, 128, 0, 63));
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(2f));
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);

    double size = (series.getMaxY()- series.getMinY())/ values.size();

    
    ValueAxis yAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    yAxis.setAutoRangeMinimumSize(size);
    yAxis.setRange(series.getMinY()-size, series.getMaxY()+size);
    
    DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis();
    xAxis.setRange(start, end);
    xAxis.setVisible(false);
    plot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
    plot.getRangeAxis().setVisible(false);
    
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0d, 0d, 0d, 0d));
    
    plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
    
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
    
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    
    try {
        File file = new File("./file/output.png");
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
        }
        ChartUtils.saveChartAsPNG(file, chart, 500, 200);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: It sound like you want a smooth line like [`XYSplineRenderer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+XYSplineRenderer). What does "color of the area can be gradually changed" mean? A gradient paint? An animation?

Comment: I am sorry, it is a gradient paint

Comment: It looks like you can use a gradient paint in `setSeriesPaint()`; I don't see any support for spline-bounded areas.

Comment: I want [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZjHQ.png), I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: It looks like you would need a custom renderer; alternatively, you could use polynomial regression to fit your data. In any case, please please [edit] your question to include the new image and a [mre] that focuses on your revised approach.